# Count duplicate value but no count on blank in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I would like to count the duplicate value in google sheet, my formula is counting the duplicate value.
However, When i added the new row for many, the formula is auto generated count as duplicate.
So, it is already showing 'Yes' on the sheet.

My excel sheet formula is `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS($A2:$A, A2:A)=1, "","YES"))`

[image]

I would like to count the duplicate value without effecting when adding the new row?

Answer (score 0):

Use-

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS($A2:$A, A2:A)>1,"YES",""))
```

But I will advise to use new dynamic formula `MAP()`. Try-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,x)>1,"Yes","")))
```

[image]